# Correcting NET::ERR_CERT_DATE_INVALID

Tags: 12.04, certificates

When trying to open a https site on my server, for which I bought a SSL-certificate, I get a NET::ERR_CERT_DATE_INVALID error in chrome.

What do I have to do on my ubuntu server to fix this?

This is a headless server, I only have console access, so no gui approaches please.

Answer (score 1):

Similar problems happened on my laptop (with Ubuntu 18.04 LTS) that wasn't turned on for quite a while. The system time gets wonky and is at least 18hrs off.

Everything else works fine but the issue raised when Google Chrome refuse to open any webpage.

This seems to fix the issue by correcting the system time.

```
sudo apt install ntp
timedatectl set-ntp true
```

See [Enable System clock synchronization](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1046214/enable-system-clock-synchronization) for other alternative fix.

Answer (score 0):

One of two things has happened.

1. Your certificate has expired
2. The system time is wrong

Comment: `date` gives `Mi 28. Okt 05:32:19 CET 2015` - How to check for the expiry date? EDIT: I found `echo | openssl s_client -connect mydomain.com:443 2>/dev/null | openssl x509 -noout -dates`. How do I prolong it?

Comment: Does that command indicate that the cert is expired?

Comment: `notBefore=Sep 15 15:59:50 2012 GMT; notAfter=Sep 15 15:59:50 2013 GMT;` was the result