# Why does local time reset itself to wrong time after "timedatectl set-time"?

Tags: server, 20.04, time, ntp

I have a server (Ubuntu 20.04) with an asynchronous time (wrong by around 7.5 minutes; RTC already seems to be equal/close to the "real" time) which I want to correct:

```
timedatectl
               Local time: Do 2021-04-08 14:32:02 CEST
           Universal time: Do 2021-04-08 12:32:02 UTC
                 RTC time: Do 2021-04-08 12:24:16
                Time zone: Europe/Berlin (CEST, +0200)
System clock synchronized: no
              NTP service: n/a
          RTC in local TZ: no
```

To do so I have included some time servers in my `/etc/ntp.conf` (as described [here](https://www.pool.ntp.org/en/use.html)) and restarted ntp via `sudo service ntp restart`:

```
server 0.de.pool.ntp.org
server 1.de.pool.ntp.org
server 2.de.pool.ntp.org
server 3.de.pool.ntp.org
```

Then I did `sudo timedatectl set-time 14:25:00` to [set the system clock to the specified time](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/timedatectl.html) so that the unsynchronized system time will be rather close to the "real" time.

Afterwards the time actually seems to be (more) correct (although saying "System clock synchronized: no"):

```
timedatectl
               Local time: Do 2021-04-08 14:25:04 CEST
           Universal time: Do 2021-04-08 12:25:04 UTC
                 RTC time: Do 2021-04-08 12:25:04
                Time zone: Europe/Berlin (CEST, +0200)
System clock synchronized: no
              NTP service: n/a
          RTC in local TZ: no
```

But suddenly (about half a minute later) I get this again (Local/Universal time != RTC time):

```
timedatectl
               Local time: Do 2021-04-08 14:33:15 CEST
           Universal time: Do 2021-04-08 12:33:15 UTC
                 RTC time: Do 2021-04-08 12:25:29
                Time zone: Europe/Berlin (CEST, +0200)
System clock synchronized: no
              NTP service: n/a
          RTC in local TZ: no
```

What kind of mechanism may interfere here which resets the "Local time" to the wrong time every time again?

**[Update]**

Ok, by now I have understood that there are actually two separate ways to manage/sync the time in Ubuntu:

**Old way:**

`ntp` (more exactly `ntpd` with its config file `/etc/ntp.conf`)
-> which is probably still installed on my system as it has been upgraded several times from older Ubuntu distributions

**New way:**

`timesyncd` which seems to be the new way [since Ubuntu 16.04](https://ubuntu.com/server/docs/network-ntp) (with config file `/etc/systemd/timesyncd.conf`):

> [...] That shall ensure that no two time syncing services are fighting. While no more recommended to be used, this still also applies to ntpd being installed to retain any kind of old behavior/config that you had through an upgrade. But it also implies that on an upgrade from a former release ntp/ntpdate might still be installed and therefore renders the new systemd based services disabled.
>
> ntpdate is considered deprecated in favor of timedatectl (or chrony) and thereby no more installed by default. timesyncd will generally do the right thing keeping your time in sync [...]

**Attention: ntp/ntpd != NTP protocol**

The old `ntpd` service which I suppose is installed via `sudo apt-get install ntp` is not the same as the NTP protocol itself.
This caused a lot of confusion when reading articles about this issue because in the context of `timesyncd` the NTP protocol is of course used but this has nothing to do with the `ntp` installation/`ntpd` command as I understand it.

Comment: When using `timedatectl` you should be setting your NTP servers in `/etc/systemd/timesyncd.conf` not in `/etc/ntp.conf` since that file is used directly by the `ntp` command.  Servers are separated by spaces in the `/etc/systemd/timesyncd.conf` file.

Comment: There is no `/etc/systemd/timesyncd.conf` file on my server. Does this mean that using `timedatectl` is actually not the preferred way to manage the time on my server?

Comment: I'm not sure what it defaults to when the file doesn't exist.  However, the file is normally commented out anyway so you could create one and then set your servers in it.  Arch Linux has a good example there:  https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/systemd-timesyncd  With systemd the timedatectl is the preferred way.

Comment: However, if you want to use `ntp` it still can be installed into 20.04.  https://askubuntu.com/a/1046217/231142

Comment: I have updated my question.

I suppose my problem is caused by the old `ntpd` still running which interferes with `timesyncd` which has probably been installed when upgrading Ubuntu to 16.04.

I will try to uninstall `ntp` so that `timesyncd` can be used for everything without interference (hopefully).

Comment: Installing timesyncd again should remove ntp. Run the command `sudo apt install systemd-timesyncd`. Then refer to some of [these answers](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1046214/enable-system-clock-synchronization) to configure timesyncd.

Comment: I did it the other way round (uninstalled `ntp` which automatically installed/configured `systemd-timesyncd` so that it worked) as described in my 2nd update. Seems to have worked as well. :-)

Comment: Glad it worked either way. :-) For your Q&A to follow the standards of this site, you should extract your answer from your original question (including the steps you took to make it work), and post it as your own answer that you accept. In that way, the question and the solution are clear and separate for future reference.

Comment: Thanks for the clue! I will mark it as correct answer as soon as I am allowed to do it. :-)

Comment: Glad you got it working.  +1 for your answer below.  However, even though `ntp` is deprecated, I bet the issue with that was is that the `ntpd` was not started for it to keep sync.  I have had both on my system before and my time was really accurate, but you really only need one.  Since `systemd-timesyncd` is the newer replacement, it is favored heavily now over the old `ntp`.  I am not 100% sure though that `ntp` is fully deprecated as an update was released back in 2020 http://support.ntp.org/bin/view/Main/SoftwareDownloads  But anyway, whatever way works is the way to go.

Comment: For the sake of completeness:

At least `sudo systemctl status ntp` had told me that it was `active (running)` when I was still having the issues.
However, the same output said `kernel reports TIME_ERROR: 0x2041: Clock Unsynchronized` as well.

Comment: Since you fixed it, it doesn't really matter now.  But, `ntpd` is started by running `sudo /usr/local/bin/ntpd -n` or `sudo /usr/sbin/ntpd -n`.  `systemctl` cannot control the `ntpd` since it is not a systemd service.  `ntpd` is the daemon that forces the ntp sync to happen.  When the `ntpd` is working properly the command of `ntpq -p` will actually produce info about all the ntp server connections and their jitter, offset, etc.

Comment: I can confirm that for another long standing machine which is also out of sync. `ps -ef | grep ntp` shows that a process `/usr/sbin/ntpd [...]` is running which confirms that the system is still using the old service.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I still don't know why that original issue (time reset back to wrong time) has actually happened but I could get my time finally working by uninstalling `ntp` (`sudo apt-get remove ntp`) which automatically installed and configured `systemd-timesyncd` instead so that all my system times finally set themselves to the correct setting:

Still asynchronous after installation:

```
$ timedatectl
               Local time: Fr 2021-04-09 14:04:45 CEST
           Universal time: Fr 2021-04-09 12:04:45 UTC
                 RTC time: Fr 2021-04-09 12:12:31
                Time zone: Europe/Berlin (CEST, +0200)
System clock synchronized: yes
              NTP service: active
          RTC in local TZ: no
```

Some minutes later everything is finally fine:

```
$ timedatectl
               Local time: Fr 2021-04-09 14:08:54 CEST
           Universal time: Fr 2021-04-09 12:08:54 UTC
                 RTC time: Fr 2021-04-09 12:08:54
                Time zone: Europe/Berlin (CEST, +0200)
System clock synchronized: yes
              NTP service: active
          RTC in local TZ: no
```

Thanks a lot for your help!

Answer (score 0):

RTC is the real-time-clock, the BIOS-battery powered hardware time. Your BIOS-battery might be failing and as a result the drift of the hardware clock is worse then it should be.

Comment: The problem was not that the time drifted more and more but that it suddenly set itself back to the 7.5 minute offset after about one minute after it was set manually to the correct time.