# Why is the time not syncing?

Tags: sync, time, clock, ntp

I want the time to sync, but it's not. I tried running the following commands, but it's still not syncing.

```
# timedatectl set-ntp off
# timedatectl set-ntp on
# timedatectl status
                      Local time: Fri 2021-08-06 20:01:43 EDT
                  Universal time: Sat 2021-08-07 00:01:43 UTC
                        RTC time: Fri 2021-08-06 20:01:43
                       Time zone: America/New_York (EDT, -0400)
       System clock synchronized: no
systemd-timesyncd.service active: yes
                 RTC in local TZ: no
```

Edit: More info

```
systemctl status systemd-timesyncd
● systemd-timesyncd.service - Network Time Synchronization
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/systemd-timesyncd.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Sat 2021-08-07 15:26:10 EDT; 58min ago
     Docs: man:systemd-timesyncd.service(8)
  Process: 9351 ExecStart=/lib/systemd/systemd-timesyncd (code=exited, status=238/STATE_DIRECTORY)
 Main PID: 9351 (code=exited, status=238/STATE_DIRECTORY)


# journalctl -u systemd-timesyncd
1]: systemd-timesyncd.service: Service has no hold-off time, scheduling restart.
1]: systemd-timesyncd.service: Scheduled restart job, restart counter is at 5.
1]: Stopped Network Time Synchronization.
1]: systemd-timesyncd.service: Start request repeated too quickly.
1]: systemd-timesyncd.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
1]: Failed to start Network Time Synchronization.
```

Running Ubuntu 18.04. Internet works and can browse the internet.

Comment: Which distro and version of Linux are you using? Is is it a desktop or a server. Is the internet connection working? Please edit your question and add these information.

Comment: Did you add any NTP servers to the `/etc/systemd/timesyncd.conf` file to help with synchronization?  After I added servers to the `NTP=` line my `timedatectl status` now showed yes for sync.

Comment: I never edited the default timesyncd.conf file. It is all comments except `[Time]`

Comment: what do you get when you run $`sudo hwclock` 
is it an accurate time or something else?

Comment: See https://askubuntu.com/a/1106011/231142 as they show how to configure the `timesyncd.conf` file and restart the service.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Apparently there was a directory permissions bug and it affects multiple distros. The solution is simple.

```
$ sudo chmod 0700 /var/lib/private
$ sudo systemctl restart systemd-timesyncd
$ sudo timedatectl status
```

Also, this may or may not be needed:

```
$ sudo rm -r /var/lib/private/systemd
```

Source:
https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=233277

Answer (score 1):

1. Check you ntp configuration in /etc/ntp.conf

$ cat /etc/ntp.conf

```
...
pool 0.ubuntu.pool.ntp.org iburst 
pool 1.ubuntu.pool.ntp.org iburst 
pool 2.ubuntu.pool.ntp.org iburst 
pool 3.ubuntu.pool.ntp.org iburst
```

edit the file if necessary (`nano /etc/ntp.conf`)

2. Run the following command to restart the service

`sudo service ntp restart`

3. Lastly, if you have an UFW firewall enabled on your system you will need to open the NTP UDP port 123 for incoming connections:

`$ sudo ufw allow from any to any port 123 proto udp`

Comment: `Failed to restart ntp.service: Unit ntp.service not found` It appears not to be installed. I thought systemd was supposed to replace ntp?

Comment: See this post: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-time-synchronization-on-ubuntu-18-04

Comment: Thanks, but I'd rather not switch to ntp. Perhaps there is a way to get timesyncd to work?

Comment: The last part helped me. I had to open 123 port in my firewall, not just for incoming but outgoing too

Answer (score 0):

Check logs: journalctl -u systemd-timesyncd

My problem was about root distance parameter (I have bad Windows Server sync server). Increase RootDistanceMaxSec from default value 5 to 15 fixed my problem.

https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/timesyncd.conf.html