# Does Default Ubuntu use ntpd or timesyncd?

Tags: systemd, ntp, systemd-timesyncd

In the question linked, I ask how I can get time syncing to work. [Why is the time not syncing?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1356425/why-is-the-time-not-syncing)

The answer given was to check my NTP configuration. Why would I do that? I thought Ubuntu switched from `ntp` to `timesyncd` when systemd was adopted. What is the Default time syncing method on Ubuntu?

Ubuntu 18.04

Comment: "Why would I do that?"  should be a comment in the other question not a new question.  " I thought Ubuntu switched from ntp to timesyncd when systemd was adopted?" The question is not asking about what Ubuntu uses but what YOU use.

Comment: It depends on *which* Ubuntu you are using which is the default.  Because they changed and at one point e

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Default Ubuntu uses `timesyncd`, and this has been the case since Ubuntu 15.04 (April 2015)

Source: [Rationale for switching from upstart to systemd?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/613366/rationale-for-switching-from-upstart-to-systemd)